# Impact of Supercompacts on Measurables

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

It is consistent that the least measurable cardinal can carry exactly one normal measure but in almost all models for this theory there is no supercompact cardinal. It seems existence of a supercompact cadinal *forces* the least measurable cardinal to have *many* normal measures. Equivalently this means that the assumption "there exists exactly one normal measure on the least measurable cardinal" is an *anti-large cardinal* axiom which refutes existence of any large cardinal larger than supercompacts.

**Question:** Assuming consistency of $\text{ZFC}$ and some suitable large cardinal axiom, is the following consistent?

**ZFC + There exists at least one supercompact cardinal +**

**The least measurable cardinal carries exactly one normal measure**

Comment: You'll need to assume the consistency of much more than $ZFC$ to make this question nontrivial, since $ZFC+$"There exists at least one supercompact cardinal" already has consistency strength well above that of $ZFC$. (That said, I really like the question!)

Comment: @NoahS: Thank you for your notification. I fixed it.

Comment: Well, the least measurable has to have Mitchell order of $0$ anyway. So that's a promising start. I can't contribute much more, but as @Noah said, it's a nice question.

Comment: The natural idea is to show that if V satisfies GCH and $\kappa$ is the least measurable in it, then there is a set forcing notion which ensures that only one ultrapower embedding can lift.

Comment: @Mohammad: Can one do that? If yes, then one does not destroy the supercompactness of $\delta$, and the answer is positive.

Comment: I don't know the answer, that's just an idea. It seems that the paper by Friedman-Magidor does not help, because they start from L[U].

Comment: @MohammadGolshani: Mohammad, Please introduce the related references. Can you give me more explanations about your idea, please?

Comment: The paper I meant is: Friedman, Magidor, 
The number of normal measures. 
J. Symbolic Logic 74 (2009), no. 3, 1069–1080.

Comment: The following might be interesting too: http://www.math.yorku.ca/~ifarah/cmsw11/cummings.pdf

Comment: @MohammadGolshani: Thanks for references.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Dear Asaf, Please explain more about the issue on Mohammad's idea.

Comment: @StGeorg: If there is a supercompact, then for every set $U$, $V\neq L[U]$. The paper Mohammad is citing begins with the assumption that $V=L[U]$, in which $\kappa$ is the only measurable and $U$ is the only normal measure on $\kappa$. So while it simplifies their work, it does not include a model where there exists a supercompact. The "right" thing to do, if so, is to analyze their proof and see if it can be carried out in a model of $\sf ZFC+GCH+\exists \delta\text{ supercompact}$.